# spring web services configuration in web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, wsdl

I am using spring-ws and I have the below configuration in my web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>**transformWsdlLocations**</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Here I have **transformWsdlLocations** configured. Please explain me the use of transformWsdlLocations here. I am using the dynamic WSDL generation concept.

Is transformWsdlLocations really required for dynamic WSDL generation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Given that it only takes a couple of minutes to remove the value and redeploy your application, I would advise you  to do that and see what happens. Just try accessing the WSDL through "localhost" and through "127.0.0.1", and see what differences there are.

However I'll explain what you should see here...

When you read the WSDL that is generated, you should find that there are URLs in there.

i.e. From the local machine you might use:

```
http://localhost:8080/myservice.wsdl
```

But when you go live, your service might be:

```
http://www.<yourdomain>.com/myservice.wsdl
```

You don't want someone downloading the WSDL from your production domain to have those values populated with "localhost:8080". Likewise, you can't test your service properly if the URL being returned in the WSDL is for your production server. Or you might have multiple production services with different URLs.

transformWsdlLocations ensures that this is generated dynamically based on whatever URL is being used to access the service.

It is not needed for dynamic WSDL generation, but I have always found it very useful to have it. However, it is not enabled by default, so if you do want those URLs to be generated dynamically then it's best to include it.

Comment: Steve, Thanks much for your reply. in spring-ws we can use either dynamic wsdl or static wsdl approach. I think if we use dynamic wsdl approach then it makes sense. If i go for static wsdl approach then still will that transformWsdlLocations is useful? Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: It also applies to static WSDL - it causes soap:address to be replaced dynamically, according to the URL being used.

Comment: Steve, below comment is from your answer. "transformWsdlLocations ensures that this is generated dynamically based on whatever URL is being used to access the service." here i am confused. Does it mean consider i deployed my service www.domainone.com/service/one.wsdl then if i try to access the service as www.domaintwo/service/one.wsdl then still the request is processed? Thanks!

Comment: As long as the second URL gets to the same place. It assumes that the WSDL will be hosted on the same server as the service itself. So the address it returns should be whatever URL the client is using to get there.

Comment: btw - This is because in theory, you could host your WSDL on a different server from your service. In that case a static soap:address would be required. However, if you are hosting your WSDL on the same machine as your working service, then a dynamic soap:address tends to make life easier.

Comment: Steve, what does " hosting your WSDL on the same machine as your working service" mean? Please could describe? Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40752/discussion-between-user755806-and-steve)

Comment: Different locations example: WSDL at http://schemas.<mydomain>.com/myservice.wsdl and your service at http://services.<mydomain>.com/myservice

Comment: Same locations example: WSDL at http://services.<mydomain>.com/myservice.wsdl and service also at http://services.<mydomain>.com/myservice

Comment: Steve, at any cost domain should be same right? in above case at any point wsdl and services should be on same domain but can be in different locations ? am right?

Comment: Assuming that you're exposing it from your spring app, that's correct.